# how to add dynamic facets in Elasticsearch and Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

i'm have a movies and music db. based on if the user is in movies or music, the facets need to change.

i've tried using .OnFields(string[]) to pass in an array (which changes based on movies/music) but i'm getting an error.

here's the code i'm using which generates the error. what am i missing?

```
string[] facetFields = new []{"genres","format","decades","price"};

var searchResult = client.Search<MyData>(s => s
            .MatchAll()
            .FacetTerm(t => t
                .OnFields(facetFields)
                .Order(TermsOrder.term)
                .AllTerms()
            ));
```

the error is:

```
"Couldn't infer name for facet of type TermFacetDescriptor`1"
```

Answer (score 1):

found the answer. you have to name the facet (i knew that but wasn't sure where) like so ...

see 'MyFacet' below...

```
var searchResult = client.Search<MyData>(s => s
        .MatchAll()
        .FacetTerm("MyFacet", t => t
            .OnFields(facetFields)
            .Order(TermsOrder.term)
            .AllTerms()
        ));
```

**if this is in the documentation somewhere - could someone point me to it?**

Thanks!